# Android ImageView NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-widget, image-manipulation, android-layout

I have two images, a red light and a green light. I have a custom ListView that I would like to display a red light when a list item is inactive, and a green light when it is active. A list item is activated when it is pressed.

Here is my code

row.xml

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iconLight"
    android:src="@drawable/light_off"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

main.java

```
ImageView iconLight = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iconLight);
iconLight.setImageResource(R.drawable.light_on);
```

I get a NullPointerException executing the line that sets the image resource. So I did a little testing, I deleted the line setting the src in the XML file and just tried to set it in the main class. Still a NPE. So I tried not changing the resource, but just changing the alpha. Still NPE.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. The files `light_off.png` and `light_on.png` are both in `res/drawable-ldpi` and either of them work when I specify them in the XML. But any change I attempt to make to `iconLight` in the main file causes this NPE. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you please paste the whole file where you get the NPE?

Comment: the file is quite a few hundred lines.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The only way to get a NPE in the line...

```
iconLight.setImageResource(R.drawable.light_on);
```

Is for *iconLight* to be null. So, your findViewById is failing. Have you set your layout before you call findViewById? Are you *sure* R.id.iconLight is in the Activity's root layout?

Comment: duh, that's the problem. man, wasn't even thinking. No, the current content view is `R.layout.main` and the ImageView is in row.xml. I wonder why Eclipse autofilled in `R.id.iconLight` then... oh well. How would I go about accessing the ImageView while leaving the current view set to main?

Comment: That should probably be a separate question (I think it might even be non trivial) but I'll say that you need to attach the imageView(s) somehow and since this is for a list, it's going to probably be done through an Adapter. How you access a single one is escaping me at the moment. Probably need to setup some callbacks when you create the view in the Adapter. Also, eclipse is dumb and auto completes *all* ids since it is not aware of which view your code is working with.

Comment: Thanks for the insight Andrew. I do have an Adapter setup to create my custom list components. When I set the imageview's resource in there it worked without error. It was dumb to assume the auto-completion in Eclipse meant the file could actually see it. I think I'll have to sit down and redo some logic here to make this work. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Here is a code that helped me understand. It is for a Dialog window but might help you too.

```
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom);
    dialog.setTitle("Title...");
    TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text);
    text.setText("Android");
    ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.image);
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

Watch the line before the last one. Notice how it instantiates the ImageView.
Anyway every change to the image is made after the setContentView.