# Android: Change Image Swipe View

Tags: java, android, imageview

I want to create a [swipe view](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html) with a few pages.

They all have the same layout, but I wanted to display other content on each page,
with ImageViews and TextViews inside.

On every swipe, I have to change the text content or the image's drawable for displaying my different pages.

So I use

```
    ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.text1))
        .setText(R.string.my_text1);
```

this works ..

But this:

```
    ((ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.image1))
        .setImageResource(R.drawable.pic1);
```

or this:

```
    ((ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.image1))
        .setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pic1);
```

doesn't.

The app crashes, and LogCat says:

```
07-31 18:31:41.467: E/AndroidRuntime(792): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-31 18:31:41.467: E/AndroidRuntime(792): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-31 18:31:41.467: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at com.keksarmee.mcguide.Friendly$ObjectFragment.onCreateView(Friendly.java:119)
07-31 18:31:41.467: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1460)
07-31 18:31:41.467: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:911)
07-31 18:31:41.467: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)
07-31 18:31:41.467: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)    
07-31 18:31:41.467: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1444)
07-31 18:31:41.467: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:461)
07-31 18:31:41.467: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:163)
07-31 18:31:41.467: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1064)
07-31 18:31:41.467: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:911)
07-31 18:31:41.467: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1432)
07-31 18:31:41.467: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
07-31 18:31:41.467: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
07-31 18:31:41.467: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
07-31 18:31:41.467: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
07-31 18:31:41.467: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:847)
07-31 18:31:41.467: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
07-31 18:31:41.467: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
07-31 18:31:41.467: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
07-31 18:31:41.467: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
07-31 18:31:41.467: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2176)
07-31 18:31:41.467: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
07-31 18:31:41.467: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1874)
07-31 18:31:41.467: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1089)
07-31 18:31:41.467: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1265)
07-31 18:31:41.467: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
07-31 18:31:41.467: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
07-31 18:31:41.467: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
07-31 18:31:41.467: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
07-31 18:31:41.467: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
07-31 18:31:41.467: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
07-31 18:31:41.467: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
07-31 18:31:41.467: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-31 18:31:41.467: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-31 18:31:41.467: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-31 18:31:41.467: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-31 18:31:41.467: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-31 18:31:41.467: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-31 18:31:41.467: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-31 18:31:41.467: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I'm sorry for copy&pasting my log...

But I couldn't find another way to change the drawable.
Eclipse is not showing any errors...

:(
Richie

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException, so there must be a method call on a `null` value somewhere. Could you run some tests to see which object is `null`? It is highly likely that some object does not exist or has been forgotten to initialize.

Comment: My current layout is page_passive.xml, but the ImageView is in page page_passive_fragment_collection_object.xml, so maybe this: `((ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.image1))` is null. (Saw it [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4393976/android-imageview-nullpointerexception))

Answer (score 1):

OK, I've found the solution.

In my xml file I have to use

```
id="@android:id/icon"
```

instead of

```
id="@+id/image1"
```